# WordPress Featured Image on Blog Page

Tags: wordpress

I want to be able to use the Featured Image on a 'blog' page.
Here is the dev site: http://splashagency.com.au/dev/jetset/travel-blog/

As you can see, right at the top of the page is a blue sky (with a bit of cloud) image. That seems to be pulled in from a post featured image but I want to be able to log in, go to Pages > Edit > Featured Image and alter it from time to time. Just like how it works on all the other pages.

But for some reason I can't seem to get it to work. Here is my index.php code:

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="category-pic" class="cf">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'package-categpry-pic' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!-- category-pic -->

<article id="content" class="left ">    

            <?php
            /* Run the loop to output the posts.
             * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
             * called loop-index.php and that will be used instead.
             */
             get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
            ?>

</article><!-- content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And yes, I realise there is a spell check on the thumbnail name!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that a typo or do you actually have a custom post thumbnail size defined as package-categpry-pic ?

Comment: Long story but yes, that's the name - no typo!! ha Don't worry it'll be changed. Just need to fix my above issue.